# Получение и отображение видеопотока через UDP протокол на C# сервере

Tags: python, c#, opencv, udp

На Rasberry pi написан UDP клиент, который берет видео с камеры и шлет на сервак.

```
   import cv2, imutils, socket
   import numpy as np
   import time
   import base64

   WIDTH=400
   BUFF_SIZE = 65536
   client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
   client_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_RCVBUF,BUFF_SIZE)
   host_name = socket.gethostname()
   host_ip = '192.168.1.104'
   port = 9999
   client_socket.sendto(message,(host_ip,port))
   vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
   fps,st,frames_to_count,cnt = (0,0,20,0)

   while True:
       while(vid.isOpened()):
        _,frame = vid.read()
           frame = imutils.resize(frame,width=WIDTH)
           encoded,buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame,[cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY,80])
        message = base64.b64encode(buffer)
        client_socket.sendto(message,(host_ip,port))
           frame = cv2.putText(frame,'FPS: '+str(fps),(10,40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
           cv2.imshow('TRANSMITTING VIDEO',frame)
           key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            client_socket.close()
            break
           if cnt == frames_to_count:
            try:
                fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                st=time.time()
                cnt=0
            except:
                pass
           cnt+=1
```

Не могу написать UDP сервер на WPF, который обработает полученные данные и отобразит видеопоток, нужна помощь.

Comment: На WPF серверы не пишутся, на WPF пишутся клиенты.

Comment: Этот комментарий холиварный и не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу, но спасибо за внимание. Мне осталось понять, что делать с данными, которые питон (cv2.imencode) преобразовал и как их раскодировать

Comment: Ну вопрос пока выглядит "напишите мне с нуля", его необходимо конкретизировать. Слушалку UDP написать не сложно, сложно понять, что вообще с этими данными принятыми делать (записать на диск? отображать?), как действовать при потере пакетов и т.д. Ну и код/xaml покажите, если имеется.

Comment: У меня нет рабочей «слушалки». Я получаю от клиента питоновского пакеты, но не могу их декодировать обратно в видеопоток. Рюшки я могу и сам дописать, но огромная просьба к умельцам и гуру: если есть опыт - покажите как можно пакеты данные обработать и вывести на экран (в любом формате))

Comment: Ну тогда покажите, как их получаете, так будет больше шансов получить ответ. Вы хотя-бы VLC проигрывателем поток пробовали воспроизвести? Он вроде умеет. Кстати, `b64encode` делать не надо, шлите байты как есть.

Comment: У меня есть Питоновский сервер, который справляется с задачей, получает и выводит поток.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то у вас такая схема: Паблишер потока - сервер - клиент, в чем дальнейшие сложности? С сервера делаете рассылку полученного потока, слушатели (в вашем случае WPF клиент) его читает и отображает. Сложности с чем именно у вас? С чтением потока? С отображением потока?

Comment: @OwDafuq сложности с тем, что бы на c# декодировать видеопоток и отобразить его, который был закодирован в питоне (при помощи cv2.imencode и base64)

Comment: https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/OpenCvSharp.Cv2.ImDecode(byte[],%20OpenCvSharp.ImreadModes)/ ?